# Error when trying to create a data store of Iterations

Tags: rally

I'm trying to get back a data store of iterations to build a board similar to the iteration planning board.  Here is my code...

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
        model: 'Iteration',
        fetch: true,
        autoLoad: true,
        context: {
            workspace: 'workspace/22050374191',
            project: 'project/27401497157',
            projectScopeUp: false,
            projectScopeDown: false
        },
        listeners: {
            load: this._onIterationsLoaded,
            scope: this
        }
    });
```

However I always get the following error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Project/27401497157?fetch=O…kDays%2CIterationEstimateUnitName%2CReleaseEstimateUnitName%2CTaskUnitName. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1337' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am creating other data stores successfully so I don't think it's a general configuration type of error.

Comment: Is it possible you don't have access to that project?  What happens if you just omit the context on your store?  Does it work then?

I'm wondering if there's some other error happening but it's surfacing as a CORS issue instead...

Comment: just to let you know I tested your code without making any changes to it (except using my workspace/project ObjectIDs) and it worked outside Rally and inside(deployed in a custom page) - so this is not a code issue. Do you see this problem when running inside or  externally outside Rally, or both? What happens if you omit the context as @KyleMorse suggested, and then also try a different project?

Answer (score 0):

The way that I've found to work around this is to clear my browser cache of images and files (but not cookies). In Chrome, go to settings (chrome://settings/clearBrowserData), and check the "Cached images and files" checkbox. I've had this error a few times while using the "rally-app-builder run" command, and it took me a while to empirically track this down.

Clearing images and files does **not** affect your cookies. In Chrome, anyhow.